# if any wordpress plugin available for malayalam font?

Tags: wordpress

I am having mayalam font.. i want to display this content in wordpress site.. but it does not display properly

My malayam font shows as following format

```
\½nÂ I¯s« DWÀÆnsâ Aán
```

how to use malayalam font in my site?

if any font plugin available for this problem?

if any other solution for that!!

Answer (score 1):

You can use a Malayalam text editor to type your blog post, and then copy and paste the text into the post editor at WordPress.com. For example, Yahoo has a web-based text editor for transliteration into Malayalam here:

http://transliteration.yahoo.com/malayalam/

I hope this helps! :)

Comment: I am having mayalam font.. i want to display this content in wordpress site.. but it does not display properly

Comment: No i think. Please check this link. This may help you. http://www.jijokjose.com/database/mysql/how-to-solve-malayalam-or-any-other-font-display-error-in-wordpress/

Comment: My wordpress post editor Does not support malayalam Font... Change mysql format for front end display errors..